# Django/ How get sum of order - 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: django

I'm trying to withdraw the order amount using the method from the model, but I can't. Have error - `'int' object is not iterable`

**models.py**

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(self.get_price())

    def get_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.order)
```

get_price method it's work, but in get_total_price have error, what I'am doing wrong?

**order_success.html**

```
{% for item in order_item %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{item.price}}</td>
        <td>{{item.get_price}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}

<h2>To pay - {{order_item.get_total_price}}</h2> # doesn't work
```

can you help me write right the sum method, please. I think my method is wrong.

Comment: It looks a bit strange to have a `get_total_price` of an `OrderItem`. You probably want to calculate an aggregate over the entire collection of `OrderItem`s?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes

Comment: @HenryM, updated question, maybe so need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you help me write right the sum method, please. I think my method is wrong.

I think your *modeling* is wrong. An `OrderItem` has no `total_price`, it has a certain `price` that is the quantity times the unit price, but the total price is an attribute of the entire queryset.

We can however calculate such aggregates, by using a queryset in the view for that, like:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

def some_view(request):
    order_items = OrderItems.object.all()  # might be a different query
    aggrs = order_items.aggregate(
        total_price=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price'))
    )
    context = {
        'order_items': order_items,
        'aggrs': aggrs
    }
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

In the template, we can then render it like:

```
{% for item in order_items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{item.price}}</td>
        <td>{{item.get_price}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}

<h2>To pay - {{ aggr.total_price }}</h2>
```

> **Note**: since your `order_item` is a collection, it makes more sense to use a plular (like `order_items` here in this sample view).

> **Note**: it makes sense to define this on the `Order` model, for example:
>
> ```
> class Order(models.Model):
>
>     # ...
>
>     @property
>     def total_price():
>         return self.order_item_set.aggregate(
>             total_price=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price'))
>         )['total_price']
> ```
>
> then we can thus write `some_order.total_price` to obtain the total price of that `Order` object.

> **Note**: it is a bit confusing that you have a `price` field and a `get_price` method, perhaps you should consider renaming `price` to
>   `unit_price`, and then make `get_price` a `@property` named `price`.